# Automation scripts execution issue with Regression Suite Automation tool for Dynamics 365 application

Tags: azure-devops, ui-automation, dynamics-365

I am trying to execute automation scripts in Regression Suite Automation tool(RSAT) and its throwing below error. I am using Dynamics 365 environment 10.0.26 and RSAT Version 2.4.11641.99.

**Status: Test case failed.
ERROR:
The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
DEBUG INFO:

System.ServiceModel.CommunicationObjectFaultedException
  The communication object, System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel, cannot be used for communication because it is in the Faulted state.
  
Server stack trace: 
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.CommunicationObject.ThrowIfDisposedOrNotOpen()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.EnsureOpened(TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannel.Call(String action, Boolean oneway, ProxyOperationRuntime operation, Object[] ins, Object[] outs, TimeSpan timeout)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.InvokeService(IMethodCallMessage methodCall, ProxyOperationRuntime operation)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServiceChannelProxy.Invoke(IMessage message)
Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   at MS.Dynamics.Performance.Application.TaskRecorder.Create_a_vendorBase.TryToConnectToEnvironment(Int32 connectionRetryCount, Int32 connectionRetryDelayInMilliseconds)
   at MS.Dynamics.Performance.Application.TaskRecorder.Create_a_vendorBase.TestSetup(Boolean verboseSnapshotsEnabled, Int32 actionTimeout, Boolean caseSensitiveValidation, Boolean groupComparison, Int32 pauseBetweenActions, String playbackDirectory, Int32 connectionRetryCount, Int32 connectionRetryDelayInMilliseconds)
**